# Referring Css and Bootstrap files

Tags: html, css, django

I have just started learning django and need some help. I have attached settings file with HTML code and its output. My HTML code is linking my css file. Am I linking it correctly or do I need to change something in settings.py file. Also I wasn't able to use bootstrap so I copied navbar example for W3school website and it ran fine. but when I replace the bootstrap link from the W3school to the one from bootstrap wesbite, it again doesn't work. And of course when I try to link downloaded bootstrap link, it doesn't work as well.
Please help me with this. I'm using django 3.1.enter image description here
[Settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEm1S.png)

Comment: Try to replace staficfiles_dirs with `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]` How did you include the css files please show the code

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"> ..... My static folder is under the projectname. I tried what you mentioned, still not working

Comment: Did you load the files on top of html file with `{% load static %}`?

Comment: yes.look at it ...<!DOCTYPE html>
{%load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>HomePage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
  
</head>